# Evitar la inserción de NULL en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

¿Alguna forma en SQL server 2008 r2 de evitar la inserción de datos **NULL** o **'pepe'**  en una tabla Antes de insertarse?. Osea que se anule la acción.

Ejemplo:

```
TRIGGER ON [dbo].[AntiNull]
ON [Valores]

AFTER INSERT
AS
IF(@valo= NULL) 
BEGIN 
NO INSERTAR
END
```

Comment: basta con que al crear la tabla pongas que la columna no acepta `NULL`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando quieres plantear una lógica a determinados valores, puedes hacer dos cosas.

**Trigger After Insert**

En el trigger after insert, tienes la opción de tirar abajo la transacción.

```
Create Table dbo.valores
 (
 id    Int Identity(1, 1) Primary Key
  , valor VarChar(100)
 );
 go
 -- Opcion 1
 Create trigger dbo.valoresAfterInsert on 
 dbo.valores
 After insert
 As
 Begin
 
    if exists (select * from inserted where (valor is null) or (valor = 'Pepe'))
        rollback tran;
 End
 go
```

Siempre hay que pensar en que no se inserta una fila, sino puede ser un conjunto de ellas, por tanto, puedes deshacer la transacción, si alguna de las filas viene con un valor no deseado, o null.

```
 Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
 values ('juan'), ('luis');
 go

Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
 values ('Oscar'),(null);
 go
```

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 La transacción terminó en el
> desencadenador. Se anuló el lote.

[image: Resultado]

```
 Drop Trigger dbo.valoresAfterInsert;
 Go
```

**Triggers Instead Of**

Otra opción son los triggers instead of, que se ejecutan antes de guardarse el dato, y que tienes que definir de un modo explicito la inserción.

```
Create trigger dbo.valoresInsteadOfInsert on 
 dbo.valores
 Instead of insert
 As
 Begin
 
    Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
        Select inserted.valor from inserted
        Where valor is not null 
            And
            valor <> 'Pepe';

 End
 go
```

En el puedes definir una serie de valores que no te interesan, de manera que si la inserción contiene esos valores, estas filas no irán, pero el resto si.

```
Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
 values ('Oscar'),(null),('Ana'),('Pepe'),('Bea');
 go
```

[image: Resultado2]

```
 drop trigger dbo.valoresInsteadOfInsert
```

[Desencadenadores Instead Of](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/03/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-instead-of/)

**Check**

Por supuesto también puedes definir restricciones, que pueden aplicar chequeos a los valores.

```
 alter table dbo.valores
 add constraint ck_valores check (valor is not null and valor <> 'Pepe');

go
  Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
 values ('Felipe'),(null),('Pepe'),('Rebeca');
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 40 Instrucción INSERT en conflicto
> con la restricción CHECK 'ck_valores'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la
> base de datos 'xxxx', tabla 'dbo.valores', column 'valor'.

```
 Insert into dbo.valores(valor)
 values
 ('Mercedes');
```

[Restricciones check](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)
[image: Resultado3]

Answer (score 0):

Al crear tu tabla puedes validar que no sea null

```
CREATE TABLE ConstraintDemo1( ID INT NOT NULL,  Name VARCHAR(50) NULL)
```